# Make contenteditable responsive with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this div:

```
<div id="test" class="test" placeholder="How's your fitness going?..." contenteditable="true"></div>
  </div>
```

I want to make it responsive. is it possible to do with bootstrap? or should I just do it with css? and how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add bootstrap classes to style or make the div responsive. I have used `col-md-12 col-sm-12` to make the `div` take full width.

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:attr(place-text);
  color:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 sol-sm-12" contenteditable="true" place-text="How's your fitness going?..."></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap grid system for responsive web page or div base web application. See the Link and read it in detail
      http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid